# Spring Data JPA: Retrieve page with N-1 objects without touching DB several times using Pageable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Using a JpaRepository in Spring Boot 2.3.5 and Java 11, I'm trying to retrieve a Page of movies and their corresponding genres (one Movie has only one Genre: it's a N-1 association):

```
@Query("SELECT obj FROM Movie obj WHERE :genre IS NULL OR obj.genre = :genre")
Page<Movie> find(Genre genre, Pageable pageable);
```

However, when genre is null (scenario where all genres must be considered), my show-sql logs are showing that JPA is touching DB again and again for each different genre.

Furthermore, surprisingly, if I simply call the built-in `findAll` method, JPA is also touching DB for each different genre:

```
Page<Movie> result = movieRepository.findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

A native query should work around, but I'd like to use my Pageable object. So how could I retrieve a page with N-1 objects without touching DB several times using Pageable?

Comment: Use `FETCH JOIN` to eagerly load the `Genre` assuming it is an entity. Something like `SELECT obj FROM Movie obj FETCH JOIN obj.genre WHERE :genre IS NULL OR obj.genre = :genre`

Comment: @M.Deinum JOIN FETCH works for List, but not for Page. Throws the following error: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

Comment: Weird, that shouldn't matter. Might be due to the count being issued with a page. You can try specifying a dedicated count query next to the regular query, then do that without a fetch join.